# Tranferring POSIXct to date gets rid of time. Need to change date capitalization on big dataset

Tags: r

I am working with a data set that has all three letters capitalized for the abbreviation of the month ("21MAY68:15:00"), and another that just has the first letter abbreviated("21May68:15:00"). My goal is to merge them by date.
My problem is that logic doesn't recognize equal dates due to the difference in capitalization so I try to reformat the one that is all capitalized.

```
date<- "21MAY68:15:00"
format(date, format="%d%b%y:%H:%M")
"21MAY68:15:00"
```

which makes sense. I then think to go through some (needed) change to then change back to this format; but when I make it to as.Date this gets rid of the time!

```
date<-as.POSIXct(date, format= "%d%b%y:%H:%M", tz= "EST")
date<- gsub("2068", "1968", date)
date<-format(as.Date(date), format="%d%b%y:%H:%M")
21May68:00:00
```

I haven't been able to find much help on this since it seems most times that as.Date is used is when you don't mind the time all that much.

Alas, I have tried to lower the specific last two letters of the month

```
X<-substring(date, 4, 5)
x<-tolower(X)
gsub(X, x, date)
21May68:15:00
```

which works! but the dataset is 436,000 rows and R wants to terminate before its able to complete the for loop.....
I am now thinking to extract the original time and add it to the as.Date format....maybe there's a simpler way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need the `%Y` instead of `%y` as `%Y` is for 4 digit and `%y` for 2 digit

```
format(as.Date(date), format="%d%b%Y:%H:%M")
[1] "21May1968:00:00"
```

---

Not clear based on the description.  if the intention is to just change into camelcase

```
date<- "21MAY68:15:00"
sub("([A-Z])([A-Z]+)", "\\1\\L\\2", date, perl = TRUE)
[1] "21May68:15:00"
```

Comment: Thank you! I do not care about having the four-digit date. I didn't know what camelcase was but yes this is my intention, and wow does this code work fast! Can you explain what the quotes in the sub command mean? Specifically, "\\1\\L\\2"?

Comment: @rod22 It is the backreferences for the capture groups i.e. the characters captured inside the `()`.  The `\\1` corresponds to `([A-Z])`) and `\\2` for `([A-Z]+)` i.e. one or more upper case letters.  In the replace we use `\\L` to lower the case of the second backreference

Answer (score 0):

The code that you have can be used in a vectorised way so you would not need a `for` loop. We would need to replace `gsub` with `str_replace`.

```
X <- substring(df$date, 4, 5)
x <- tolower(X)
df$date <- stringr::str_replace(df$date, X, x)

df
#           date
#1 21May68:15:00
#2 25Apr68:15:00
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(date = c("21MAY68:15:00", "25APR68:15:00"))
```

Comment: Thank you! This fixed it. I would upvote but don't have enough reputation:/